# Is the absolute speed of light invariant or its speed relative to us?

Tags: speed-of-light

Is it correct that beforethe Michelson Morley experiment did they believe that the absolute motion of light was always the same regardless of what produced it but assumed it's speed measured by us changed based on our motion? I'm quite confused about it :s

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes - possibly the title or maybe that History of Science and Mathematics *could* be a better home for the question, but it's a thoroughly reasonable question. Yes, at least from my understanding of the history, that's a correct assessment of the situation, because that's the behavior of acoustic waves in a material medium.  People assumed that Maxwell's equations only held in their wonted (as Maxwell stated them) form in the rest frame of the aether.

Answer (score 1):

To not go off into discredited theories like Emission Theory and probably others the story is quite simple.

The community thought that the speed of light was c with respect to the medium it traveled in, called the aether (or ether). MM proved that it did not depend on the motion of the observer. Good enough to say there was no aether. So Einsten got the equations of SR from c being the same in all coordinate systems, the source, the observer, or any other observers reference frame (with constant velocity or in inertial frames, which is the same)

There's not much more to that.

Lorentz had said it was some contraction of space in the direction of motion, and got the Lorentz contraction equation, but Einsteins SR put it all together, and allows you to get Lorentz contraction, time dilation, how to add velocities in two frames, and the transformation laws for momentum and energy.

Other explanations were all discredited.

Answer (score -1):

Yes before the Michelson-Morley experiment they believed that the speed of light was independent of the speed of the source but varied with the speed of the observer. In 1887 (prior to FitzGerald and Lorentz advancing the ad hoc length contraction hypothesis) the Michelson-Morley experiment UNEQUIVOCALLY showed that the speed of light varied with the speed of source as well, as predicted by Newton's emission theory of light:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_theory 
 "Emission theory, also called emitter theory or ballistic theory of light, was a competing theory for the special theory of relativity, explaining the results of the Michelson–Morley experiment of 1887. [...] The name most often associated with emission theory is Isaac Newton. In his corpuscular theory Newton visualized light "corpuscles" being thrown off from hot bodies at a nominal speed of c with respect to the emitting object, and obeying the usual laws of Newtonian mechanics, and we then expect light to be moving towards us with a speed that is offset by the speed of the distant emitter (c ± v)."

http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1743/2/Norton.pdf 
 "The Michelson-Morley experiment is fully compatible with an emission theory of light that CONTRADICTS THE LIGHT POSTULATE."

Comment: Michelson-Morley showed that the speed of light varied with the speed of the source ? I'm not sure I follow, I think Michelson-Morley showed the exact opposite, no ?